# How to execute Vim commands in looped functions

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a function to simplify the command to switch windows in Vim.
I have managed to get it to work as `:W <argument>`:

```
function! s:winswitch(...)
          let i = 0
          while i < argc()
                  let command = ":wincmd ".a:1
                  execute command
                  let i = i + 1
          endwhile
  endfunction
  command! -nargs=+ W call s:winswitch(<f-args>)
```

This works in making `:W l` function as `:wincmd l`.

I'm looking for a way for it to execute the commands based on an arbitrary number of arguments such as I can use `:W j h` to function as `:wincmd j|wincmd h`.

Comment: In this particular case, you can do without args/loops at all: `command! -nargs=+ W execute "normal! \<C-W>" . join([<f-args>], "\<C-W>")`

Comment: Or `"wincmd ".join([<f-args>], "|wincmd ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional function arguments `(...)` are available in the List [`a:000`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#a%3A000), in addition to the separate `a:1`, `a:2`, ...

You actually don't need to use the length (via `a:0`, not `argc()`!) and explicit indexing if you switch from `:while` to a `:for` loop:

```
for arg in a:000
    let command = 'wincmd ' . arg
```

If for some reason you need to use indexing, I would still prefer `:for`:

```
for i in range(a:0)
    let command = 'wincmd ' . a:000[i]
```

Comment: without explicit indexing does seem cleaner hmm

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is in `argc()` — it doesn't count the arguments to the function, it counts the file arguments in the command line. Most probably `argc()` is 1 when you run the code so the loop is executing only once.

To count the arguments to the function use [`a:0`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#function-argument) instead of `argc()`:

```
while i < a:0
    let command = ":wincmd " . a:000[i]
```

Comment: Ah interesting but how do I access each individual argument in the loop? Surely if if I do :W j l, a:1 will be j so it would function like wincmd j|wincmd j rather than wincmd j| wincmd l

Comment: `a:{i}` looks better IMO. But one have to count from `1` to `a:0` in this case.